# SVG not rendering in browser on page load

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having issues with google chrome and other browsers that SVG icon is not rendering while added it through CSS in my web page. which added background for custom dropdown.

Here is the sample of SVG code

```
background: #fff url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg viewBox='0 0 140 140' width='20' height='20' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><g><path d='m121.3,34.6c-1.6-1.6-4.2-1.6-5.8,0l-51,51.1-51.1-51.1c-1.6-1.6-4.2-1.6-5.8,0-1.6,1.6-1.6,4.2 0,5.8l53.9,53.9c0.8,0.8 1.8,1.2 2.9,1.2 1,0 2.1-0.4 2.9-1.2l53.9-53.9c1.7-1.6 1.7-4.2 0.1-5.8z' fill='%23b91a10'/></g></svg>") no-repeat;


 select {
            font-size: 14px;
            padding: 9px 16px;
            border-width: 2px;
            border-style: solid;
            font-family: Arial, san-serif;
            border-color: #342000;
            color: #000;
            background: #fff url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg viewBox='0 0 140 140' width='20' height='20' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><g><path d='m121.3,34.6c-1.6-1.6-4.2-1.6-5.8,0l-51,51.1-51.1-51.1c-1.6-1.6-4.2-1.6-5.8,0-1.6,1.6-1.6,4.2 0,5.8l53.9,53.9c0.8,0.8 1.8,1.2 2.9,1.2 1,0 2.1-0.4 2.9-1.2l53.9-53.9c1.7-1.6 1.7-4.2 0.1-5.8z' fill='%23b91a10'/></g></svg>") no-repeat;
            background-position: right 5px top 50%;

            -webkit-appearance: none;
            -moz-appearance: none;
            appearance: none;
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue - https://jsfiddle.net/3mg2z6ec/, Please make a [`MCVE`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: it's not loading while it's placing inside my web page.

Answer (score 2):

You must target an element! like ( Body, div..etc) to see your data.

```
    body {
  background: #fff url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg viewBox='0 0 140 140' width='20' height='20' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><g><path d='m121.3,34.6c-1.6-1.6-4.2-1.6-5.8,0l-51,51.1-51.1-51.1c-1.6-1.6-4.2-1.6-5.8,0-1.6,1.6-1.6,4.2 0,5.8l53.9,53.9c0.8,0.8 1.8,1.2 2.9,1.2 1,0 2.1-0.4 2.9-1.2l53.9-53.9c1.7-1.6 1.7-4.2 0.1-5.8z' fill='%23b91a10'/></g></svg>") no-repeat;

}
```

I tried your code on jsfiddle and it's working when you traget an element to set your background.

Comment: it's loading while running in a single test page.. but not loading in my web page.

Comment: Make a jsfiddle for your project, then we can track the issue.